# Writing to FIFO FILE, Linux & Mono(C#)

Tags: c#, linux, mono, fifo, mkfifo

I want to do what I wrote in the title. But I just simply can't get my head around it. I also googled everythng. I want to write strings to file of special type FIFO, created by mkfifo (I think). If there are any other suggestions how to do this, you are welcome.

```
static class PWM
{

    static string fifoName = "/dev/pi-blaster";

    static FileStream file;
    static StreamWriter write;

    static PWM()
    {
        file = new FileInfo(fifoName).OpenWrite();

        write = new StreamWriter(file, Encoding.ASCII);
    }

    //FIRST METHOD
    public static void Set(int channel, float value)
    {
        string s = channel + "=" + value;

        Console.WriteLine(s);

        write.Write(s);

        // SECOND METHOD
       // RunProgram(s);
    }

    //SECOND METHOD
    static void RunProgram(string s)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "bash";
        string x = "|echo " +s+" > /dev/pi-blaster";
        Console.WriteLine(x);

        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = x;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

        proc.Start();
       // proc.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SOLUTION!!!! PI-BLASTER WORKS :D :D (lost 2 days of life because of this)
write.flush was critical, btw.

```
namespace PrototypeAP
{
static class PWM
{

    static string fifoName = "/dev/pi-blaster";

    static FileStream file;
    static StreamWriter write;

    static PWM()
    {
        file = new FileInfo(fifoName).OpenWrite();

        write = new StreamWriter(file, Encoding.ASCII);
    }

    //FIRST METHOD
    public static void Set(int channel, float value)
    {
        string s = channel + "=" + value + "\n";

        Console.WriteLine(s);

        write.Write(s);
        write.Flush();
    }
}
}
```